# 'Simplification' of 夠

Tags: simplified-characters, orthography

Why did 夠 get 'simplified' into 够?

I'd like to know whether these existed as orthographic variants before simplification (such that the first round simplifications just standardised on one variant) or if there was some other basis, perhaps ideological, for either choosing one of the two forms, or creating a new form with 多 on the RHS.

Answer (score 6):

This is discussed extensively in this thread:
http://forum.reviewingthehanzi.com/viewtopic.php?id=7698

A quote

> Because the "simplified" version of this character was made PRC
>   standard when the new character lists were published. Even though
>   nothing was actually simplified. There was a committee in China tasked
>   with simplifying and standardizing written Chinese, when they came
>   across this character they noticed there were two common versions of
>   the hanzi being used so they had to pick which one will be in the
>   official government approved lists. 够 won out.

Comment: good link.. taught me a lot about the "simplification" process

Comment: 漢簡委更喜歡俗體字而已。多三字