# 沒 simplified to 没: What is the origin of the change?

Tags: glyph-origin, traditional-vs-simplified

I've just discovered that the simplified form of the character 没 is different from the traditional form (沒). With them both being nearly identical with exception of a single stroke, why was there a need to alter it at all? Does anyone here know the origin of the change?

Comment: It’s important not to get too caught up in labels. “Simplification” is an umbrella term for a bunch of stroke-cutting procedures, rather than an actual writing standard. 没 is a character in the writing standard (PRC Chinese or *Jōyō* Japanese) - the standard may have characters which are the same or even more “complex” than “Traditional Chinese”.

Comment: Most simplified Chinese characters are nonsense when compared to traditional ones, especially its logical structure. For details please google 六書.
One more funny fact for the following character:
Traditional Chinese: 強
Simplified Chinese: 强
Which has one more stupid stroke and dare to call simplified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Simplification" is a process. If it's not reduced in stroke count, it's not actually "Simplified" - the mix-up in language is due to PRC's standard of Chinese being popularly known as "Simplified Chinese", even though PRC Chinese may have [the same number of](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/simplification-of-%e5%a4%a0) or even [more strokes](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/10258/why-does-the-simplified-chinese-character-%e5%bc%ba-have-more-strokes-than-its-tradition).

「没」 came from a popular variant of 「沒」, because the right hand side of 「没」, 「殳」, occurs more frequently among characters, while the right hand side of 「沒」, 「」, occurs in...「沒」.

---

It is important to look at a character's earliest traceable meaning before further analysing its components.

- Some of the earliest traceable meanings of 「沒」 is *to be underwater / be submerged* (cf. 「沉沒」). This is the reason for its 「氵・水」.
- 「殳」, if it's a semantic component, is usually used as an active verb marker, cf. 「發」 (*to shoot arrows* > *emit*), 「擊」 (*to attack*), 「殺」 (*to kill*), etc. 「殳」 is therefore not a semantic match for the meaning *submerge* (and is not a phonetic match for the sound of the word either).

So, what exactly is 「沒」?

> <kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> [秦](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)103
> [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd>
> <kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> 「沒」 was originally a compound of a *hand* 「又」 under *deep waters* (represented by a *whirlpool* 「洄」). 「回」 was later gradually corrupted into the shape of 「勹」 or 「刀」.
>
> <kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
> [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image]
> 602
> [銀雀山簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yinqueshan_Han_Slips)編</kbd><kbd>[三國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Kingdoms)・[魏](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_Wei)
> 隸
> [image]
> 孔羨碑</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> Note: as a consequence of this development, we can be certain that 「」 was not really a character before, but was made up to decompose 「沒」 into 「氵・水」 and something else.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 《王力古漢語字典》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [漢字源流](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/search_source.html)

Comment: " the right hand side of 「没」, 「殳」, occurs more frequently among characters, while the right hand side of 「沒」, 「」, occurs in...「沒」." Suffice to say, the right hand side of 沒 doesnt render and is not a known character on android

Comment: @小奥利奥 ah, sorry. My answers will use alot of [CJK Unified Ideograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs) extension characters. Actually, my own Iphone can't view the characters I type. Unfortunately, these characters are necessary to get the point across.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you even call this simplified?

No, it's called 新字形 ('New character forms'). Check out wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xin_Zixing  https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E6%96%B0%E5%AD%97%E5%BD%A2

Answer (score -2):

No that’s not even simplified. It has only improved the writing. It’s exactly the same character.